# how to delete data and update data from two different tables at the same time in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im a student and new in laravel
`I have a music app with three different user types, namely "user" with type_id = 3, "DJ" with type_id = 2, and "admin" with type_id = 1

pada halaman admin terdapat daftar user dan juga DJ dengan aksi "hapus"

DJ List

```
ID_______| 1 __________ | 2 __________ |    
NAME____ | john_______  | jane________ |    
CHANNEL  | john channel | jane channel |    
ACTION__ | delete ______| delete ______|
```

User List

```
ID _____| 3 ____ | 4 ____ |
NAME__  | dave__ | mike__ |
ACTION  | delete | delete |
```

this is what i need

if the admin clicks "delete" on the user, I just want to delete all the data itself on the users table

and if the admin clicks on "delete" on the DJ, I want to delete all his data from the users table and also update the user_id whose value is the same as the id of the DJ on the channel table to "NULL"

what can i do to get those things ?

Users Table

```
ID______| 1___ | 2___ | 3___ | 4____|
TYPE_ID | 2___ | 2___ | 3___ | 3____|
NAME __ | john | jane | dave | mike |
```

Channels Table

```
ID______| 1__________  | 2__________  | 3_________ |
USER_ID | 1__________  | 2__________  | NULL_____  |
NAME __ | john channel | jane channel | Channel #3 |
```

Here my controller

```
UserController.php

public function index()
{
     $djs = User::join('channels', 'users.id', '=', 'channels.user_id')
                     ->select('users.*', 'channels.name as channel_name')
                     ->where('type_id', '=', '2')
                     ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                     ->get();
     $users = User::where('type_id', '=', '3')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

 return view('dashboard.manageUsers', compact('users', 'djs'));
}

public function destroy(channel $channel, $id)
{
    User::find($id)->delete();

    $channel = App\Channel::find($channel->id);
    $channel->user_id = NULL;
    $channel->save();

    return redirect('/dash/manage-users');
}
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::delete('/users/{id}/delete', 'UserController@destroy');
```

manageUsers.blade.php

```
<h5 class="light">DJ List</h5>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>channel</th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($djs as $dj)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $dj->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dj->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dj->channel_name }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" action="/users/{{ $dj->id }}/delete">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                        <button class="btn-flat">delete</button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<h5 class="light">User List</h5>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" action="/users/{{ $user->id }}/delete">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                        <button class="btn-flat">delete</button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please forgive me, but what means _pada halaman admin terdapat daftar user dan juga DJ dengan aksi hapus_ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//delete
 public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        // Delete for image coding
       if(Storage::disk('public')->exists('uploads/post/'.$post->image))
       {
           Storage::disk('public')->delete('uploads/post/'.$post->image);
       }
    // Delete code for zipfile
       if(Storage::disk('public')->exists('uploads/zip/'.$post->zip))
       {
           Storage::disk('public')->delete('uploads/zip/'.$post->zip);
       }
        $post->categories()->detach();
        $post->tags()->detach();
        $post->delete();
        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Deleted :)','Success');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

//update

    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
         $this->validate($request,[
            'title' =>'required',
            'image' => 'image',
            'categories' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
             'live_demo' =>'required'
        ]);





          $image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->title);
        if (isset($image))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());   
            $image_resize->resize(1600,1066);
            if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/post'))
            {
                mkdir('storage/uploads/post',0777,true);
            }
            unlink('storage/uploads/post/'.$post->image);
            $image_resize->save('storage/uploads/post/'.$imagename);
        }else{
            $imagename = $post->image;
        }

        $post->user_id = Auth::id();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->slug = str_slug($request->title);
        $post->image = $imagename;
        $post->zip = $zipname;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->price = $request->price;
        $post->live_demo = $request->live_demo;
        if(isset($request->status))
            {
                $post->status =true;
            }else
            {
                $post->status = false;
            }
        $post->is_approved = true;
        $post->save();
        $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);



        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Updated:)','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.post.index');
    }

//blade
<button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" type="button" onclick="deletepost({{ $post->id }})">
                                            <i class="material-icons">{{__('delete')}}</i>
                                        </button>
                                        <form id="delete-form-{{ $post->id }}" action="{{ route('admin.post.destroy',$post->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                        </form>
```